# How to make condition in Flutter

Tags: flutter, conditional-statements, widget

There is two files that have similar code, it is add and update area feature, that I decide to make it only one, with using condition.

You can see that two features have similar widgets, only different in texts.

In my case, when user want to adding area, the UI will display add area feature. When user want to updating area, the UI will display update area feature, but it only from one codebase.

Is it possible to make that kind of condition?

Here I copy paste the whole codes of add area feature. I don't have to copy paste update area because it has the similar codes.

```
class AddItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddItem({super.key, this.isUpdate = false});
  final bool isUpdate;

  @override
  State<AddItem> createState() => _AddItemState();
}

class _AddItemState extends State<AddItem> {
  String selectedCategoryItem = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 366,
      width: 514,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 25,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 434,
            height: 42,
            child: Wrap(
              alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text(
                  widget.isUpdate ? 'Add Item' : 'Update Item',
                  style: heading2(
                    color: ColorName.blackPrimary,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                  child: InkWell(
                    child: SvgPicture.asset(
                      Assets.icons.closeIcon.path,
                      width: 16,
                      height: 16,
                    ),
                    onTap: () => {
                      Navigator.pop(context),
                    },
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 435,
            child: Wrap(
              alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                Wrap(
                  direction: Axis.vertical,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Item Code',
                      style: body1(
                        color: ColorName.blackPrimary,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 126,
                      height: 60,
                      child: TextField(
                        style: body1(color: ColorName.blackPrimary),
                        cursorColor: ColorName.blackPrimary,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Item Code',
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: ColorName.grey,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Wrap(
                  direction: Axis.vertical,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Category Item',
                      style: body1(
                        color: ColorName.blackPrimary,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 288,
                      height: 56,
                      decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          side: BorderSide(
                              style: BorderStyle.solid, color: ColorName.grey),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(10),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: DropdownButton<String>(
                        icon: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, top: 8),
                          child: SvgPicture.asset(
                            Assets.icons.dropdownIcon.path,
                            fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                          ),
                        ),
                        style: body1(color: ColorName.blackPrimary),
                        items: <String>[
                          'Burger',
                          'Ice cream',
                        ].map((String value) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: value,
                            child: Text(value),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                        hint: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, left: 10),
                          child: Text(
                              style: body1(color: ColorName.grey),
                              selectedCategoryArea.isEmpty
                                  ? 'Category Item'
                                  : selectedCategoryArea),
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        underline: const SizedBox(),
                        isExpanded: true,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          if (value != null) {
                            setState(() {
                              selectedCategory = value;
                            });
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 425,
            child: Wrap(
              alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 183,
                  height: 60,
                  child: OutlinedButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                        RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      side: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                        const BorderSide(
                          color: ColorName.darkBlue,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      'Cancel',
                      style: subtitle1(
                        color: ColorName.darkBlue,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 183,
                  height: 60,
                  child: OutlinedButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                        ColorName.darkBlue,
                      ),
                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                        RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      side: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                        const BorderSide(
                          color: ColorName.darkBlue,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      widget.isUpdate ? 'Add Item' : 'Update Item',
                      style: subtitle1(
                        color: ColorName.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (widget.isUpdate) {
                        AddSuccess().showCustomDialog(context);
                      } else {
                        UpdateSuccess().showCustomDialog(context);
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 25,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use ternary operator? Ex: `Text(action == Action.add ? "Add Area" : "Code Area")`

Comment: Yeah, something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to define from where you know that the screen is updating screen or adding screen. I mean like

```
class AddItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool isUpdate;
  const AddItem({super.key, this.isUpdate=false});//IT MEANS THAT isUpdate is FALSE by default, but you can define it while creating AddItem
  ...
}
```

Then in your widgets you can do like this:

```
Text(
  widget.isUpdate?'Update Item':'Add Item',
  //if it is inside Stateless widget then you use isUpdate? instead of widget.isUpdate
  style: subtitle1(
  color: ColorName.white,
  ),
),
```

Inside functions like `onPressed` you can just use like this:

```
onPressed: (){
   if(widget.isUpdating){
     AddSuccess().showCustomDialog(context);
   }else{...}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I run into a problem. Your code is working, but now the two features have changed into Update Area. Do you know what's my mistake? I have edited my question, you can take a look

Comment: It is because isUpdate has default false value. When you create AddAreaItem(isUpdate: true) it will be Add when youncreaye AddAreaItem() or AddAreaItem(isUpdate: false) it will be Update. isUpdate is parameter for the widget. I hope you undertand this. If not, don’t hesitate to ask.

Comment: You can also declare it not as a parameter. You can create a variable in _AddAreaItemState and change it with setState

Comment: Where I have to use setState? You know that Text widget don't have onTap or onPressed parameter.

Comment: You are not forced to use setState. I said if you want. It is totally related to your app logic. If you need isUpdate as a parameter(doesn't change for the current page internally) or as a just variable inside State class(you have capability of changing the screen without popping it). It is totally up to you. Generally, I answered your core question, how to make condition statement in flutter. Other things are related your app logic and implementation. So please, kindly upvote&accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass those two values in the properties when rendering this widget. Then check if the properties are null then you are trying to add new data. But if those contains the value then its updating the data.

Something like this

```
class AreaWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const AreaWidget({super.key, this.areaCode, this.areaName});
  final int? areaCode;
  final String? areaName;

  @override
  State<AreaWidget> createState() => _AreaWidgetState();
}

class _AreaWidgetState extends State<AreaWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(widget.areaCode == null ? "Add Area" : "Upate Area"),
    );
  }
}
```

You can then check value and make the changes according to the value. Even inside the function as well to call the specific add or update related code.